# Understanding nested PHP ternary operator

Tags: php, ternary-operator, operator-precedence

I dont understand how that output ("`four`") comes?

```
$a = 2;

echo
  $a == 1 ? 'one'   :
  $a == 2 ? 'two'   :
  $a == 3 ? 'three' :
  $a == 5 ? 'four'  : 
    'other'  
  ;

// prints 'four'
```

I don't understand why "`four`" gets printed.

Comment: It will be printed for $a = 5;

Comment: @riky: yes, but `$a=2` in his code...

Comment: @riky @Marco, can anyone tell me how parser does parse that code?

Comment: YA so according to your login it will print "two". Can you explain me what exactly you want?

Comment: Syntax `cond ? true_part : false_part` is the same as `if (cond == true) true_part else false_part`. So your code should print two. Strange...

Comment: @riky you misunderstand. That statement is not written correctly so it will print 'four'. The OP wants to know why it does this.

Comment: @riky I want to know How this code will be parsed by parser?

Comment: @Jimit : May be 2 is not assigned to 'a' properly. Try to print he value of 'a'

Comment: @JohnP Yes, right John .

Comment: == operator has grater precedence level than ternar operator. So you must use brackets to group.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: @MatejB Add that as an answer. It's the only correct answer to this question.

Comment: @MatejB, I know I should use brackets man! but I want to know how that hell output being generated by parser?

Comment: Apart from being completely unreadable, you should avoid stacking ternary operators. See the note in the manual http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Were any of the answers below acceptable?

Comment: In C/C++/Java you would get "two". The actual reason why PHP differs is because PHP handles `?:` associativity from left to right, instead of right to left. This is a well know PHP misdesign. See [this explanation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php#91377) and [that criticism](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/#operators). This question is not off topic as this is a real and problematic PHP precedence issue.

Comment: It's important to note that with PHP 7.4, using of nested ternary conditions is deprecated, and you have to use parenthesis: see https://wiki.php.net/rfc/ternary_associativity and https://3v4l.org/K0Qr8

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to bracket the ternary conditionals:

```php
<?php

for ($a=0; $a < 7; $a++) {
  echo (
    $a == 1 ? 'one' :
    ($a == 2 ? 'two' :
    ($a == 3 ? 'three' :
    ($a == 5 ? 'four' : 'other'))));
    echo "\n";
    // prints 'four'
}
exit;
?>
```

returns:

```
other
one
two
three
other
four
other
```

as you'd expect.

See the note at the bottom of "Ternary operators" at [PHP Ternary operator help](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

The expressions are being evaluated left to right. So you are actually getting:

```
  echo (
    ((($a == 1 ? 'one' : $a == 2)
     ? 'two' : $a == 3) ? 'three' :
    $a == 5) ? 'four' : 'other');
```

So for `$a=2`, you get:

```
  echo (
    ((($a==2) ? 'two' : $a == 3) ? 'three' :
    $a == 5) ? 'four' : 'other');
```

and then

```
  echo (
    ((true ? 'two' : $a == 3) ? 'three' :
    $a == 5) ? 'four' : 'other');
```

and then

```
  echo (
    ('two' ? 'three' : $a == 5) ? 'four' : 'other');
```

and then

```
  echo (
    'three' ? 'four' : 'other');
```

and so `echo 'four'`.

Remember that PHP is dynamically typed and treats any non-zero non-null values as TRUE.

Comment: Because == operator has grater precedence level than ternar operator and hell breaks lose ;)

Comment: err, you beat me with nearly 3 minutes but the system didn't even notice me, grrr.

Comment: awesome explaination.. even i was not getting how answer this snippet. thanks dude..

Comment: This is completely opposite behavior comparing to ternary operator in other languages, e.g: C/C++ or Java. Even JavaScript does it in the right (expected) way. Anyway, as mentioned in PHP manual, it's not recommended to use nested ternary expressions

Answer (score 6):

On [the *Comparison Operators* page in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison) they explain that PHP's behavior is [*"non-obvious"*](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison#language.operators.comparison.ternary) when nesting (stacking) ternary operators.

The code you've written is like this:

```
$a = 2;

echo
  ((($a == 1  ? 'one'   :
     $a == 2) ? 'two'   :
     $a == 3) ? 'three' :
     $a == 5) ? 'four'  : 
       'other'
  ;

// prints 'four'
```

As `$a` is 2 and both `'two'` and `'three'` are TRUE as well, you get "`four`" as the result, as you don't compare any longer if `'four'` is TRUE or not.

If you want to change that, you have to put the brackets at different places [also noted by: BeingSimpler and MGwynne]:

```
$a = 2;
echo 
  ($a == 1 ? 'one'   :
  ($a == 2 ? 'two'   :
  ($a == 3 ? 'three' :
  ($a == 5 ? 'four'  : 
     'other'))))
  ;

// prints 'two'
```

Comment: @BeingSimpler: Couldn't find the link ;) Don't worry I didn't copy your code :)

Comment: I know you didn't, the system delayed a little bit. My answer above is actually 3 minutes later than MGwynne's answer, but when I posted it appeared the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Problem with grouping conditions, just need to add brackets to separate them.

```
$a = 2;
echo (
$a == 1 ? 'one' :
($a == 2 ? 'two' :
($a == 3 ? 'three' :
($a == 5 ? 'four' : 'other'))));
echo "\n";
// prints 'four'
exit;
```

Solved.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with to help myself understand left vs. right associativity for the ternary operator.

```
// PHP

$a = "T";
$vehicle =  $a == "B" ? "bus" :
            $a == "A" ? "airplane" :
            $a == "T" ? "train" :
            $a == "C" ? "car" :
            $a == "H" ? "horse" : "feet";

            // (as seen by the PHP interpreter)
            // INITIAL EXPRESSION: ((((($a == "B" ? "bus" : $a == "A") ? "airplane" : $a == "T") ? "train" : $a == "C") ? "car" : $a == "H") ? "horse" : "feet");
            // STEP 1:             (((((FALSE ? "bus" : FALSE) ? "airplane" : TRUE) ? "train" : FALSE) ? "car" : FALSE) ? "horse" : "feet")
            // STEP 2:             ((((FALSE ? "airplane" : TRUE) ? "train" : FALSE) ? "car" : FALSE) ? "horse" : "feet")
            // STEP 3:             (((TRUE ? "train" : FALSE) ? "car" : FALSE) ? "horse" : "feet")
            // STEP 4:             (("train" ? "car" : FALSE) ? "horse" : "feet")
            // STEP 5:             ("car" ? "horse" : "feet")
            // FINAL EVALUATION:   ("horse")

            // If you used the initial expression here (with the parenthesis) in a different language, it would also evaluate to "horse."

echo $vehicle; // gives us "horse"
```

This is as opposed to:

```
// EVERY OTHER LANGUAGE

var a = "T";
var vehicle =   a == "B" ? "bus" :
                a == "A" ? "airplane" :
                a == "T" ? "train" :
                a == "C" ? "car" :
                a == "H" ? "horse" : "feet";

                // (as seen by the other language's interpreter)
                // INITIAL EXPRESSION: (a == "B" ? "bus" : (a == "A" ? "airplane" : (a == "T" ? "train" : (a == "C" ? "car" : (a == "H" ? "horse" : "feet")))));
                // STEP 1:             (FALSE ? "bus" : (FALSE ? "airplane" : (TRUE ? "train" : (FALSE ? "car" : (FALSE ? "horse" : "feet")))))
                // STEP 2:             (FALSE ? "bus" : (FALSE ? "airplane" : (TRUE ? "train" : (FALSE ? "car" : "feet"))))
                // STEP 3:             (FALSE ? "bus" : (FALSE ? "airplane" : (TRUE ? "train" : "feet")))
                // STEP 4:             (FALSE ? "bus" : (FALSE ? "airplane" : "train"))
                // STEP 5:             (FALSE ? "bus" : "train")
                // FINAL EVALUATION:   ("train")

                // If you used the initial expression here (with the parenthesis) in PHP, it would also evaluate to "train."

console.log(vehicle); // gives us "train"
```

If you notice, in the PHP example, the innermost expression is on the left, and on the second example, the innermost expression is on the right. Each step evaluates the next innermost expression until there is a single result. Parenthesis are clearly very important if you're going to nest ternary operations in PHP!