# How can I understand nested ?: operators in PHP?

Tags: php, ternary-operator, operator-precedence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with PHP ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224330/problem-with-php-ternary-operator)

I was reading up a bit on PHP in [this article](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/), and I stopped for a while to consider one of his gripes. I can't figure out how on earth PHP comes to the result that it does.

> Unlike (literally!) every other language with a similar operator, ?: is *left* associative. So this:
>
> ```
> $arg = 'T';   
> $vehicle = ( ( $arg == 'B' ) ? 'bus' :
>             ( $arg == 'A' ) ? 'airplane' :
>             ( $arg == 'T' ) ? 'train' :
>             ( $arg == 'C' ) ? 'car' :
>             ( $arg == 'H' ) ? 'horse' :
>             'feet' );   
> echo $vehicle;
> ```
>
> prints horse.

What logical path does PHP follow that results in `'horse'` being assigned to `$vehicle`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php Ternary Operator Example #3

Comment: Ternary operators are great, but in PHP I'd strongly recommend that you apply a liberal amount of parentheses to them to make your desired behavior explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bracketing is the solution for both understanding *and* fixing:

This should have the *unintended* result (`horse`):

```
$arg = 'T';  
$vehicle = (
    (
        (
            (
                (
                    ( $arg == 'B' ) ? 'bus' : ( $arg == 'A' )
                ) ? 'airplane' : ( $arg == 'T' )
            ) ? 'train' : ( $arg == 'C' )
        ) ? 'car' : ( $arg == 'H' )
    ) ? 'horse' : 'feet'
);  
echo $vehicle;
```

This should have the indended result (`train`):

```
$arg = 'T';   
$vehicle = (
    ( $arg == 'B' ) ? 'bus' : (
        ( $arg == 'A' ) ? 'airplane' : (
            ( $arg == 'T' ) ? 'train' : (
                ( $arg == 'C' ) ? 'car' : (
                    ( $arg == 'H' ) ? 'horse' : 'feet'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);   
echo $vehicle;
```

Answer (score 2):

> Note:
>
> It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious:
>
> ```
> <?php
> // on first glance, the following appears to output 'true'
> echo (true?'true':false?'t':'f');
>
> // however, the actual output of the above is 't'
> // this is because ternary expressions are evaluated from left to right
>
> // the following is a more obvious version of the same code as above
> echo ((true ? 'true' : false) ? 't' : 'f');
>
> // here, you can see that the first expression is evaluated to 'true', which
> // in turn evaluates to (bool)true, thus returning the true branch of the
> // second ternary expression.
> ?>
> ```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary