# Turn 1/0 to valid/invalid

Tags: php

how i can turn in PHP the $validation output from 1/0 to the word "valid/invalid"?
Do i need json_encode($validation) in this case?

```
    $json = json_decode($content, true);

    if ($json['error'] == NULL ) {
        $country = $json['result']['countryCode'];
        $vatNumber = $json['result']['vatNumber'];
        $validation = $json['result']['valid'];               

          echo "
          <dt>Valid:</dt>
          <dd>$validation</dd>
          <dt>VAT-Number:</dt>
          <dd>$country$vatNumber</dd>

        } else {
    echo "error";
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use if-else statement or ternary operator

Comment: @sectus had a point in comments for @agro answer...I updated my answer to reflect a (secondary) validation `$validation === 1` in attempt to avoid non-desired valid returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple as 1 == true and 0 == false

```
if($validation === 1){
    $validation = 'valid';
} else {
    $validation = 'invalid';
}
```

have a reading of the php docs on [boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

Comment: thank you for this incentive. helped me a lot. i will read about boolean.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
...
<dd>" . ($validation ? 'valid' : 'invalid') . "</dd>
...
```

or with a secondary check

```
...
<dd>" . ($validation == 1 ? 'valid' : 'invalid') . "</dd>
...
```

Comment: better to be short and sweet as shown in this answer, which will get the same results as I suggested.

Comment: What about precedence?

Comment: @sectus notice [example 4](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison#language.operators.comparison.ternary) as [mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6224443/1815624) is Non-obvious Ternary Behaviour and [user3675536](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3675536/user3675536) is obviously a beginner PHP programmer...

Comment: @CrandellWS , reread answer. Try to reproduce code of the answer. Then think about operator precedence (concatenation and ternary).

Comment: @sectus I am not understanding as `$validation ? 'valid' : 'invalid'` is the same as `(($validation ? true : false) ? 'valid' : 'invalid'` only a problem if it wasn't a `1||0` `true || false` value...

Comment: @sectus A consideration from a security point `((($validation === 1) ? true : false) ? 'valid' : 'invalid')`

Comment: @CrandellWS , I am talking about operator precedence. Precedence of concationation is higher than precedence of ternary. So `echo "<dd>" . $validation ? 'valid' : 'invalid' . "</dd>";` would always output 'valid' instead of '<dd>valid</dd>' or of '<dd>invalid</dd>'. You need to add parentheses to change precedence: `echo "<dd>" . ($validation ? 'valid' : 'invalid') . "</dd>";`

Comment: he is right, so my first answer was wrong because of the precedence. 

`"<dd>" . $validation ? 'valid' : 'invalid' . "</dd>"` will be interpreted as `("<dd>" . $validation) ? 'valid' : ('invalid' . "</dd>")`.

but my second one will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array:-

```
$validOrNot = ['invalid', 'valid'];

//some other code 'n stuff
$validation = $validOrNot[$json['result']['valid']];
```