# PHP: Displaying zero to the correct output

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I am struggling to see why my code is not working when the `echo` displays `0`. The code works for everything else however whenever the random operator chooses `0` it outputs `0 Negative`, when I have it to display as `Zero`. I have no idea why it is doing this and I would appreciate any guidance.

```
$randomNumber = rand(-5, 5);
$var = $randomNumber;
echo $randomNumber;
echo $integerValue = (($var === 0) ? " Zero" : ($var <=-1) ? " Negative" : (($var >=1) ? " Positive" : " Not Positive or Zero") );
```

Comment: Ternary operators are best used if there are only 2 outcomes. For readability and easier troubleshooting, I would think about using `if` / `else` on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is due to PHP ternary operator precedence, which works backwards compared to most other languages:
[Understanding nested PHP ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224330/understanding-nested-php-ternary-operator)

Try this last line:

```
echo $integerValue = (($var === 0) ? " Zero" : (($var <=-1) 
                 ? " Negative" : (($var >=1) 
                 ? " Positive" : " Not Positive or Zero") ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to echo the assignment. You need to assign the value, then echo it. Try changing the last line to

```
$integerValue = (($var === 0) ? " Zero" : ($var <=-1) ? " Negative" : (($var >=1) ? " Positive" : " Not Positive or Zero") );
```

and then adding the line

```
echo $integerValue;
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't change the output for '0'. However thanks for the tip on changing the echo

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed the original issue you were having. Wouldn't you want anything between -1 and 1 to come back as zero? Like this: `$integerValue = (($var < 1 && $var > -1) ? " Zero" : ($var <=-1) ? " Negative" : (($var >=1) ? " Positive" : " Not Positive or Zero") );`

Comment: While not normal, the assignment will happen before the echo statement. So php will assign `$integerValue` and then echo'ing whatever value holds. Here is a quick demo: https://3v4l.org/CaemK. This is similar to how `while($row = mysqli_fetch...)` works in that row will be assigned before any expression is evaluated.

Comment: I need the output to display: '0' Zero - anything below zero as: -1 negative - and anything above zero as: 2 positive, for example

Comment: Try adding parens around the nested ternary operator like so. This will get you the outcome you are looking for: `$integerValue = (($var === 0) ? " Zero" : (($var <=-1) ? " Negative" : (($var >=1) ? " Positive" : " Not Positive or Zero")));`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parentheses:

```
<?php
$randomNumber = rand(-5, 5);
$var = $randomNumber;
echo $randomNumber;
echo $integerValue = (($var === 0) ? " Zero" : (($var <=-1) ? " Negative" : (($var >=1) ? " Positive" : " Not Positive or Zero") ) );
```

Explanation:

```
(
    ($var === 0) ? " Zero" : (
        ($var <=-1) ? " Negative" : (
            ($var >=1) ? " Positive" : " Not Positive or Zero"
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have another answer that explains why you weren't getting the outcome you expected, but just FYI, your multiple ternary expression can be simplified somewhat.

```
echo $var ? $var > 0 ? ' Positive' : ' Negative' : ' Zero';
```

`$var` will evaluate to `false` if it is zero so there's no need to explicitly compare it to zero, and the final `"Not Positive or Zero"` isn't really a possible outcome, as the result of `rand` will be an integer, which is either positive, negative, or zero by definition.

Parentheses aren't necessary, but they may make it more obvious what the expression is doing.

```
echo $var ? ($var > 0 ? ' Positive' : ' Negative') : ' Zero';
```