# Right Associativity of Ternary Operator

Tags: c++, operators, operator-precedence, associativity

```
std::cout << (true ? "high pass" : false ? "fail" : "pass")
```

is the same as

```
std::cout << (true ? "high pass" : (false ? "fail" : "pass"))
```

Since the ternary operator is right associative, why don't we perform the right-hand operation first? Shouldn't `pass` be printed instead of `high pass`?

Comment: Associativity has nothing to do with order of evaluation. Associativity governs (roughly speaking) how implicit parentheses are placed, but nothing more.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat And doesn't parenthesis dictate what operation is performed first?

Comment: They don't. [Those rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) dictate the order of evaluation. Of course parentheses set some limits on the order of evaluation, e.g. in `(1+2)*(3-(4/2))` the `*` must be evaluated last. But `/` doesn't have to be evaluated before `+`.

Answer (score 5):

You misunderstood [operator associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity). It's simply the way to **[group operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/930486/995714) with the same [precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)** and doesn't affect order of evaluation in any way. So `cond1 ? 1 : cond2 ? 2 : cond3 ? 3 : 4` will be parsed as

```
cond1 ? 1 : (cond2 ? 2 : (cond3 ? 3 : 4))
```

from the right and not as

```
((cond1 ? 1 : cond2) ? 2 : cond3) ? 3 : 4
```

which groups operands from the left. Once parentheses are "added" then the expression will be evaluated in its normal order

In fact [PHP made the ternary operator left-associative](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61915) which is one of its biggest mistake and it's unfixable by now. See [Understanding nested PHP ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6224330/995714)
**Update:** [The left-associativity of the ternary operator has been deprecated in PHP 7.4 and removed in PHP 8.0](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate/issues/3302813)

Comment: A slightly irrelevant question: Do we evaluate from left-to-right if the operator doesn't specify the order of evaluation?

Comment: @JayYay the final result in each pair of parentheses is evaluated from left to right but the order to evaluate the functions or parentheses pairs aren't defined

Comment: @JayYay It's unspecified in that case. Different compilers can do it differently.

Comment: Yeah, `PHP` really messed up there (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

The Ternary Operator works like

```
variable = (condition) ? expressionTrue : expressionFalse;
```

This could be expressed like

```
if (condition)
{
  expressionTrue;
}
else
{
  expressionFalse;
}
```

The condition of both of your statements statements is true, so the expressionTrue will be always executed. There is no reason to check the expressionFalse in a statement like

```
std::cout << (true ? "high pass" : (false ? "fail" : "pass"))
```

Comment: But doesn't associativity dictate what operation is performed first (hence the parenthesis around the right-most ternary operator)? Also, there's a mistake in your answer; one statement is false.

Comment: @JayYay *"associativity dictate what operation is performed first"* It doesn't. Associativity tells the compiler that `true ? "high pass" : false ? "fail" : "pass"` means `true ? "high pass" : (false ? "fail" : "pass")` rather than `(true ? "high pass" : false) ? "fail" : "pass"`, and nothing more.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Can you elaborate on what associativity means then? Excuse my ignorance (I'm a beginner).

Comment: @JayYay I'm not sure how to explain it (more than I already did). Another example: `a/b/c` means `(a/b)/c` rather than `a/(b/c)`, because `/` is left-to-right associative.